# Better Image Hosting for MediaWiki

Tags: images, mediawiki

We're using MediaWiki and writing a lot of articles / tutorials that require images / screenshots. Image management in MediaWiki is painful. I was hoping I could use something like Dropbox to store all the images we need and then share them via external links. However, public folders aren't sharable and I can't make shared folders public.

Is there something like Dropbox where I can easily just drop the files in a folder, they sync with all my colleagues, and I can get static URL's to the files to put on MediaWiki?

Comment: Do you need any other functionality besides a central place to store images?

Comment: Not really, other than it being Dropbox'esque simple to just drop a file in a local folder.  I know I could use AmazonS3 but with as many images as we're generating I need the simplest approach possible to get these images hosted.

Comment: Would WebDAV work in your server/desktop environment?

Answer (score 2):

Use any free image hosting services like flicker , photobucket
or use amazon S3
http://asvignesh.in/host-media-files-in-amazon-s3

Now you can use Google drive as web hosting space , Upload files to google drive get the url and use it in Media Wiki page

http://asvignesh.in/host-website-in-google-drive

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to address the MediaWiki side of the question, and leave the "where can I find a good image hosting service" part for others:

---

There are several ways to allow the embedding of external images on your wiki.  If you want to allow the embedding of external images from *anywhere*, just set [$wgAllowExternalImages](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3a%24wgAllowExternalImages) to a true value in your LocalSettings.php.

If you want to allow external images only from certain sites, you can either:

- list the URL prefixes you want to allow in [$wgAllowExternalImagesFrom](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3a%24wgAllowExternalImagesFrom), or
- set [$wgEnableImageWhitelist](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3a%24wgEnableImageWhitelist) to a true value and create the system message page `MediaWiki:External image whitelist` on your wiki.

The latter method is somewhat more flexible, both because the whitelist entries are [PCRE regexps](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php), and also because the whitelist can be edited on-wiki by sysops.

All of these methods let you just write a plain URL like `http://www.example.com/image.jpg` on a wiki page and have it be automatically converted to an image instead of an external link.  (FWIW, only URLs ending in `.jpeg`, `.jpg`, `.png` or `.gif`, in any letter case, are recognized as image links.)

As an alternative approach, you can also enable the [$wgAllowImageTag](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3a%24wgAllowImageTag) option, which lets you include raw HTML `<img>` tags on wiki pages.  There are no whitelist restrictions on allowed image URLs in that case, though.

---

Also, you don't say what you find painful about MediaWiki image management, but I'm guessing it's the fact that the built-in upload interface only allows you to upload one file at a time.  If so, note that there exist [several ways to make the process more efficient](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aConfiguring_file_uploads#Mass_uploading), either by installing a MediaWiki extension like [UploadWizard](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aUploadWizard) or [MsUpload](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aMsUpload) to provide an improved upload interface, or by using an external tool like [Commonist](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Commons%3aTools/Commonist) to automate the uploading process.